# Does the Symfony DateTimeToArrayTransformer use the names of form fields to make one value?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, mapping, field

This question is about the Symfony PHP framework.

I want to better understand how Symfony maps values of compound form types to one single value.

When you use a `DateType` form type, and configure it to use separate fields for month, day and year, it creates separate form fields, which have their own field name.

The `DateType` also has data transformers. Normally data transformers just transform the data from one format to another. But for me it seems that the `DateTimeToArrayTransformer` also gets form field names in its constructor.

See the constructor here:

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param string $inputTimezone  The input timezone
 * @param string $outputTimezone The output timezone
 * @param array  $fields         The date fields <--- See this parameter.
 * @param bool   $pad            Whether to use padding
 *
 * @throws UnexpectedTypeException if a timezone is not a string
 */
public function __construct($inputTimezone = null, $outputTimezone = null, array $fields = null, $pad = false)
{
//...
```

[DateTimeToArrayTransformer on github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToArrayTransformer.php#L34)

I can't find any more information on the internet about the `fields` parameter. But I get the impression that it means the field names of existing form fields.

Of course, Symfony has to collect the form field values of the `month`, `day` and `year` field, to make one string value. But does it do this with a datatransformer, or in another way?

That's what I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTimeToArrayTransformer` takes `$fields` as argument because it's used in a few form types and it's not always year, month and day.

It's utilized in in `TimeType`, `DateType` and `DateTimeType`. All of them need to be transformed into `\DateTime` object to array and reverse, but each of them has different parts of full datetime.

Look into `TimeType`, `DateType` and `DateTimeType` classes to see how `$fields` argument is constructed.

`DateTimeToArrayTransformer` needs this information to be able to build suitable `\DateTime` object or vice-versa, parse `DateTime` object into a proper array of values.

In `transform` (`\DateTime` to array) it does intersection of full array of datetime parts with the required, which means *"give my only these parts, that I want"*.

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array(
    'year' => $dateTime->format('Y'),
    'month' => $dateTime->format('m'),
    'day' => $dateTime->format('d'),
    'hour' => $dateTime->format('H'),
    'minute' => $dateTime->format('i'),
    'second' => $dateTime->format('s'),
), array_flip($this->fields));
```

On the other hand in `reverseTransform` (array to `\DateTime`), it uses `$fields` to validate if passed array contains all required parts:

```
   ///if any of required field does not exists, add to `$emptyFields`
   foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($value[$field])) {
            $emptyFields[] = $field;
        }
    }

    //if  there is some field missing, throw an Exception
    if (count($emptyFields) > 0) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException(
            sprintf('The fields "%s" should not be empty', implode('", "', $emptyFields)
        ));
    }
```

In general `DataTransformer` class can take any arguments you want, as long as you can pass them in the place where you're create an instance of it, which is usually inside a `FormType`.

Comment: See https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php#L120 on that line, does `array('year', 'month', 'day')` contain actual form field names (like the field names used in the builder in the lines above), or is it something else? Does it refer to the names used in the builder?

Comment: Well, yes, they are unprefixed form field names. Actual html `<input>`s would probably contain some form prefix. But it's just how this form types and this tranformer are designed to work together. It's not a rule in general.